# JavaScript inheritance: When where's my derived members?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

Take a look at the following code:

```
function Primate() {
    this.prototype = Object;
    this.prototype.hairy = true;
}

function Human() {
    this.prototype = Primate;
}

new Human();
```

When you inspect `new Human()`, there's no `hairy` member. I would expect there to be one. Is there another way I'm suppose to inherit from `Primate`? Something involving `Object.create()` (ECMAScript5 is fine to use in my scenario)?

Comment: You must read this to understand inheritance in js: http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html and http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You want to manipulate the `prototype` objects of the constructors - `Primate` and `Human`. The newly created instance (the `this` value inside the constructor) is *not* a function and therefore adding a `prototype` property to is nonsensical.

Comment: I would create and extend objects (with Object.create) instead of monkey patching the prototype chain. Using functions as constructors can lead to confusion because this is implementing JavaScript objects as class-like structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your code is written, objects created using `new Human()` will have a property called `prototype` whose value is a reference to the `Primate` function. That's clearly not what you want (and it's not particularly special).

A few things:

- You usually want to modify the `prototype` of a *function* that's intended to be used as a constructor (with the `new` operator). In other words, you want to set the `prototype` on `Human` (not on an *instance* of `Human`).
- The value you assign to the `prototype` should be an *instance* of the desired type (or, if no initialization work is necessary, the desired type's `prototype`), not a reference to its constructor.
- It's never necessary to explicitly assign `Object` (or `Object` instances) to a function's `prototype`. This is implicit.

You probably want something more like this:

```
function Primate() {
    this.hairy = true; 
}

function Human() {}
Human.prototype = new Primate();
Human.prototype.constructor = Human;

var h = new Human();
```

The `Human` referenced by `h` has a property called `hairy` whose value is true.

In the previous example, `hairy` is assigned its value only once `Primate` is invoked, which is why `Human.prototype` must be assigned an instance of `Primate`. This could instead be written so that no such initialization is necessary.

Example:

```
function Primate() {}
Primate.prototype.hairy = true;

function Human() {}
Human.prototype = Primate.prototype;
Human.prototype.constructor = Human;

var h = new Human();
```